# pandas fillna Currently only can fill with dict/Series column by column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the following `df`,

```
A
1.0
2.0
3.0
NaN
```

I tried to `fillna` to replace `NaN` with a string `not existed`.

```
df.fillna(value={'A': 'not existed'}, axis=1, inplace=True)
```

but I got the following error,

```
NotImplementedError: Currently only can fill with dict/Series column by column
```

if I use `replace`, it will work,

```
df['A'].replace(np.nan, 'not existed')
```

I am wondering why is that.

Comment: in case you prefer it, there is the trivial way: `df['A'] = df['A'].fillna('not existed')`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For me working removing `axis=1`:

```
print (df)
     A    B
0  NaN  NaN
1  2.0  7.0
2  3.0  8.0
3  NaN  7.0

df.fillna({'A': 'not existed'}, inplace=True)
print (df)
             A    B
0  not existed  NaN
1            2  7.0
2            3  8.0
3  not existed  7.0
```

---

```
df.fillna({'A': 'not existed', 'B':'nwwww'}, inplace=True)
print (df)
             A      B
0  not existed  nwwww
1            2      7
2            3      8
3  not existed      7
```

Comment: yes, you are rite. in case there are 2 columns that I want to remove `NaN`, `df[['A', 'B']].fillna(value={'A': 'not exist', 'B': 'not exist'}, inplace=True)`, `NaN` could not be replaced with the string

Comment: dont use `subset` - `df[['A', 'B']]`, then it working perfectly. Check edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

When you use fillna on a DataFrame you should pass a dictionary with values for each column you want to fill as described [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html).

In any case, your error is related with the way in which you use `axis`, take a look to this working example:

```
import pandas

x = pandas.DataFrame({
    'x_1': [0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, None, ],},
    index=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])

x.fillna(value={'x_1': 'not existed',}, axis=0, inplace=True)
```