# Why NaN in column "endtemp" is not replaced?

Tags: python

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as img
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
%matplotlib inline


data = pd.read_csv('http://www.biointelligence.hu/ids/fuel_data_with_errors.txt', header=0, sep='\t')

data.fillna(method="backfill",axis = 1)
```

I don't understand why NaN (No.95 row) in `endtemp` is not replaced with "on".  (I know "on" is not a proper value for `endtemp`)

Answer (score 0):

"on" is a value in the "**air**" column not the "**endtemp**" column. Using axis=1 will replace NaN in that column with non NaN values succeeding them in the same column.

Therefore, since the endtemp column only contains numbers, the NaN's replaced in that column will be numbers.

Comment: Thank you.  one more question, why "inplace = True" does't work here ? I run data.fillna(method="backfill",axis = 1, inplace = True), but it gives error.

Comment: I looked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48523762/pandas-fillna-currently-only-can-fill-with-dict-series-column-by-column.

removing the axis argument will allow you to use inplace=True.

It is possibly because the axis argument makes a copy of each vector in that axis, and therefore cannot be done in place. Although I do not know for sure.